# How to limit the input to only 5 Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the JS file for making Input Tagging. I want to limit the inputs from the user to only 5 tags. I Thought of doing a `if` statement in the calling of `addTag()` function, but it didn't help me any way.

This is the JavaScript for my website which is handling the tagging section of my website.

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function (el) {
  let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input'),
      mainInput = document.createElement('input'),
      tags  = new Array(5);

  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', el.getAttribute('data-name'));

  mainInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  mainInput.classList.add('main-input');
  mainInput.addEventListener('input', function () {

    let enteredTags; let s=0;

    if( enteredTags = mainInput.value.split(" ") ){
      if(s<5){
        if (enteredTags.length > 1 ) {
          enteredTags.forEach(function (t) {
            let filteredTag = filterTag(t);
            if (filteredTag.length > 0)
              addTag(filteredTag);


          });
          mainInput.value = '';
          s++;
        }
        else if(s > 5)
        {
          alert("5 Tags Allowed");
        }
      }
    }

  });

  mainInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    let keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 8 && mainInput.value.length === 0 && tags.length > 0) {
      removeTag(tags.length - 1);
    }

  });

  el.appendChild(mainInput);
  el.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  addTag('hello!');

  function addTag (text) {
    var size = 0;

    var tag = {
      text: text,
      element: document.createElement('span'),
    };

    tag.element.classList.add('tag');
    tag.element.textContent = tag.text;

    let closeBtn = document.createElement('span');
    closeBtn.classList.add('close');
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      removeTag(tags.indexOf(tag));
    });
    tag.element.appendChild(closeBtn);

    tags.push(tag);

    el.insertBefore(tag.element, mainInput);

    refreshTags();
    size++;


  }

  function removeTag (index) {
    let tag = tags[index];
    tags.splice(index, 1);
    el.removeChild(tag.element);
    refreshTags();
  }

  function refreshTags () {
    let tagsList = [];
    tags.forEach(function (t) {
      tagsList.push(t.text);
    });
    hiddenInput.value = tagsList.join(',');
  }

  function filterTag (tag) {
    return tag.replace(/[^\w -]/g, '').trim().replace(/\W+/g, '-');
  }
});
```

[This is a glimpse of my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmQsy.png).
I want to add tags on the search by tag box.

Comment: Is there any error in console ? do you get your alert message if more than 5 tags entered

Comment: why don't you use jquery ! It's more easy to handle I think

Comment: @VinodLouis No, I don't get a alert message that's where the problem is

Comment: your s value is always 0 and your else and else if condition both are true in case of greater than 5 tags

Comment: add a working snippet

Comment: @VinodLouis So how can i make it false if it crosses 5

Comment: no need of s variable and its if condition remove it replace `enteredTags.length > 1` by `enteredTags.length < 6` and else condition no need of esle if

Comment: Should `enteredTags = mainInput.value.split(" ")` return true/false in the `if` condition?? I doubt. This is the block where is the `alert` your never getting. Have a closer look there.